# Magento not adding to cart

Tags: php, magento, e-commerce, magento-1.9.1

On my development server I am having an issue with Magento not adding items to cart. Upon trying to add an item to cart I get sent to the cart screen saying cart is empty and cannot add item to cart.

I have searched possible issues without being able to find the answer.

Magento version is 1.9.1 and for some reason in var/log there are no log files to help me locate the issue.

Any help appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: can you provide code and/or logs?

Comment: Can provide code if required, which parts would you want to inspect? As regards to logs, for some reason I am not getting any logs...

Answer (score 0):

Magento 1.9 expects form key value in various actions like add to cart, update cart, customer login etc. So you might need to add:-

```
 <?php echo $this -> getBlockHtml('formkey'); ?>
```

to your add to cart phtml file . It will add an hidden input field for formkey which may fix your issue.

Comment: Add this into the form in the cart.phtml file and it did not fix the issue

Comment: Did you upgraded your Magento  or when did you start getting this issue?

Comment: The issue started when I put it onto my staging server. On my local environment it works fine.

Comment: I fixed the issue, it was a problem with the routing the the tmp/ directory